# A counterexample in balanced parentheses

Tags: java, beginner, stack, balanced-delimiters

In this program I had to analyse if the parenthesis given are well balanced. For instance, `input (())` is correct and `input ())(()` is incorrect. I've tested with other similar inputs, so my question is: can my code fail with some weird expression (using parentheses) or will it always work correctly?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<String> parenthesis = new Stack<>();

    System.out.println("Introduce the length of your expression");
    int l = x.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduce your expression");

    x.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce an element");
       String e = x.next();
        parenthesis.push(e);
    }

    analysis(parenthesis);
}

public static void analysis(Stack<String> st) {

    Stack<String> closed = new Stack<>();//only for parentesis like this: )



    int ww = 0;
    while (!st.isEmpty() && ww != 1) {
        String s =st.pop();
        if (0 == s.compareTo("(") && !closed.isEmpty()) {
            closed.pop();
        } else if ((0 == s.compareTo("(")) && closed.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("incorrect expression.");
            ww = 1;
        } else {
            closed.push(s);
        }
    }
    if (ww == 1) {
        System.out.println();
    } else if (!closed.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("incorrect espression");
    } else {
        System.out.println("correct");
    }

}
  }
```

Comment: It seems to me that `((x)` would pass, when it shouldn't

Comment: @janos no, it works correctly. I didn't consider arguments inside the parenthesis but if you just put as input: (() the output will be 'incorrect expression'

Comment: Are stacks part of the exercise or is it your choice to use stacks to solve this problem?

Comment: I never see the point of these exercises. In real life you are writing a compiler, or at least some kind of expression parser, and if you do either of those correctly the management of balanced parentheses falls out almost as a side-effect. It isn't something you need to learn how to do separately, or to practice.

Comment: @EJP Like most pedagogical exercises, the point is not to teach you how to make the concrete thing you're told to build. The point of the exercise might have been to teach Michelle how to use String methods and stacks and Scanners. Or it might have been an exercise in thinking things through, and not going overboard with naive OO. Comparing the code shown above with a more reasonable "just count the stack depth" is quite a teachable moment.

Comment: @永劫回帰 it's part of the exercise to use Stacks

Comment: A better exercise, which you might consider trying right now is: modify your code so that it detects correct vs incorrect strings in the language of balanced parentheses with `{}[]()` parens.  So `({()[]}[])` would be legal but `({())}` would not be. Now it is not so simple as just counting how many opens and closed you see; you have to *actually use the contents of the stack* to solve this problem, and not, as others have noted, simply use the stack as a complicated integer.

Comment: Hint: the way you've written the code is not wrong, but it is more complicated than it needs to be. Try this: Make an empty stack. Go through the inputs. When you see a `(`, push it on the stack. When you see a `)`, check to see if the stack is empty; if it is, you have a bad input. If not, pop the stack. If you end up with a non-empty stack, you have a bad input. Otherwise you have a good input.  This program should be much shorter and simpler than yours.

Comment: `0 == s.compareTo("(")` seems a far stretch. What is wrong is `"(".equals(s)` ?

Comment: my teacher never use`.equals` he always use `.compareTo` @RobAu

Comment: @Michelle do you know why? Because it doesn't improve readability and is more prone to causing `NullPointerException`s (when `s == null`) than the equals in my comment.

Comment: @RobAu I don't know, I remember one time when I asked him about the meaning of `.equals`...he didn't know the meaning (when to use it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `analysis` method, you only use the variable `ww` as `0` or `1`. This would be better as a `boolean` type instead of `int` type.

---

Currently `analysis` has two actions:

1. Validate the input
2. Write the response to the console.

The `analysis` would be more reusable if you removed the printing and put it in a different function. And then `analysis` would return `String` instead of `void`.

This:

```
public static void analysis(Stack<String> st) {
...<snip>...
    if (ww == 1) {
        System.out.println();
    } else if (!closed.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("incorrect espression");
    } else {
        System.out.println("correct");
    }
}
```

becomes

```
public static String analysis(Stack<String> st) {
...<snip>...
    if (ww == 1) {
        return "\n";
    } else if (!closed.isEmpty()) {
        return "incorrect espression\n";
    } else {
        return "correct\n";
    }
}
```

---

Some of your variable names are really good (such as `parentheses`), but some are only a single letter or two, which can be hard to understand by someone else reading your code. `l` would be better as `length`, `x` could be `scanner` or `input`, etc. I still haven't figured out what `ww` is, other than a flag of some kind.

---

Is there a reason the user needs to type each character in the parentheses one at a time instead of all at once?

---

You have a typo in one of your `incorrect espression` blocks. And one ends with a period while the other does not.

Comment: why would be better to use `ww` as a `boolean` type variable?

Comment: I feel more comfortable typing character in the parentheses one at a time, it's just an option, also I don't see disadvantages on doing it

Comment: @Michelle you only ever use two values for `ww` and only check for equality. To me, that sounds exactly like a `boolean` type. This signals to others using your code that it will either be true or false, and shouldn't be part of any math or counting. As for input, it seemed hard to use to me, but I'm thinking ahead to someone trying to provide input on the command line and not as an interactive prompt.

Comment: @Michelle If you gave `ww` a meaningful name it would be easier to tell what the proper type is.

Comment: @Barmar it is like a flag, so maybe it should be called "flag"

Comment: @Michelle That's too generic. The name of a flag variable should say what condition it's flagging. E.g. in a search function you might call it `found`, in a validation function it might be called `valid`.

Comment: But in general, flags are boolean, since they're either on or off.

Comment: I see, well in my program the flag show when an error appear, so maybe it should be named `found` found a mistake. @Barmar

Answer (score 31):

May I suggest a simpler solution: 
You need only a counter. it is incremented by 1 whenever you encounter an openning parenthesis "(" and is decreased by 1 whenever you encounter a closing parenthesis ")" 
The input is invalid if the counter drops below zero or is not zero by the end of scanning.

**EDIT**
since OP specified they must use a stack, we can follow [@JollyJoker's advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175928/a-counterexample-in-balanced-parenthesis/175939#comment333879_175939): counter increament is implemented by a push operation, counter decrement by a pop one.  counter falling below zero is implemented by attemt to pop when the stack is empty. by the end of scanning the stack has to be empty.

Comment: what if you receive as input: ')(' ? it shouldn't be correct

Comment: on the first ")" the counter gets below zero...

Comment: in my answer I meant if (the counter drops below zero) or (is not zero by the end of scanning) so the input is invalid the instant the counter gets below zero which really mean an extra closing parenthesis

Comment: very nice/short/good answer but it's part of the exercise to use Stacks :( (that's why the tag)

Comment: @Michelle You can think of the stack size as the counter.

Comment: if you put as input: `(a+b)`, counter will be `0` and therefore the input will appear as incorrect, but it's correct.

Comment: `couter == 0` by the end of scanning is condition for correct input...

Comment: so this will be correct then `) (` ,first is -1 and then is 0

Comment: we've been over this before. you should be able to answer this yourself by now

Comment: or what if you have `( ( ) `, the output would be 1, so it will be interpreted as 'correct' but it's not.

Comment: the counter has to be 0 (the stack has to be empty) by the end of scanning...